# Python: syntax doesn't work

Tags: python

I have this Python code:

```
file2.write(link) + '\n' + '\n' + '\n'
```

Why doesn't it work, but the following does:

```
file2.write((link) + '\n' + '\n' + '\n')
```

Comment: Why do you expect the first one to work? What do you expect either of them to do? Have you tried decomposing the steps and examining the input and output of each one? (i.e. look at `link`, look at `link + '\n' + '\n' + '\n')   These are rhetorical questions; I don't so much need to know the answers, but asking that sort of question yourself is a good way to figure out these things.

Answer (score 6):

The former calls the function and then adds strings to the result, which is likely invalid, and certainly incorrect. The latter adds strings together and calls the function, passing the result of the addition.

Answer (score 1):

The parentheses for the write function should enclose everything you want to write to the file. In the first example, you write(link), then give a bunch of meaningless new line characters after that's done.

In the second example, you write( link + newlines ), with the closing parenthesis for the write function coming only at the end. Hence that works. (though write( (link) ) is somewhat overkill)

In summary: use a source code editor that highlights matching parentheses for you. It makes these errors easier to spot.

Answer (score 0):

```
file2.write(link) + '\n' + '\n' + '\n'
```

You are writing the content of the `link` variable into the file `file2`. This call is returning None if it succeed, and you are concatenating the strings `'\n'` to this result. At the end, only the content of the `link` variable will be in the file `file2`.

```
file2.write((link) + '\n' + '\n' + '\n')
```

You are concatenating the content of the `link` variable to the strings `'\n'` first, using the parentheses to set the priority to the string concatenation. And then writing all of them into the file `file2`.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `file2.write()`, `write()` is a function on the object `file2`.  The `link` is an argument to the function that is a string.  When you write `+ '\n' + '\n' + '\n'`  That expression evaluates to the string `"\n\n\n"`.  If you want to write `link` and that string you must pass them as one string argument to the function `write()`.  This is accomplished by `file2.write((link) + '\n' + '\n' + '\n')`.  Otherwise you are just calling the function and trying to concatenate the string to the return value of the function call.